# Longitudinal data - formule

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data

I have the following experimental design and I´m a bit lost:

I have subgingival samples collected from 30 patients. Two samples were taken from each patient on a first visit (V1):

A sample from a tooth that has not received any treatment (V1-C)
A sample from the treated tooth (V1-T) (In each patient sample C and T were taken at the same time)
Sampling was repeated for all patients two months after first visit (V2).

Therefore, Tooth has two levels (Control, treatment) and Visit two time points (V1, V2).

In other words, I have 120 samples: 30 V1-C, 30 V1-T, 30 V2-C and 30 V2-T and I am interested in fitting a Linear Mixed-Effects Model. I want to know how Shannon index changes between two time points and the teeth (treatment vs control).

I have two questions:

- Is the following model correct?

`fm <- lmer(Shannon ~ Visit * Tooth + (1 | patientID), data = my.data.frame)`

It is worth making clear that two samples were taken from each patient at visit 1 and another two at visit 2.

- Can I use Linear Mixed-Effects Models with only two time points?

Comment: The model formula looks reasonable, giving each id a different basic value and each condition a value to add to the basic value. Yes, two time point are no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!